# How to search inside a list for a different instance of a specific element?

Tags: c#

So i have a list l of elements of a class called Point, and i want to remove from this list with another series of Point, im  using this code:

```
po = new Point(x,y);
if (l.Contains(po))
l.Remove(po);
```

What happens is that the condition is never satisfied(i suppose cause the list doesnt contain obviously the new Point but another instance generated elsewhere)
Isnt there a way for contains to just check if the element is identical even if not the actual same instance?

Comment: Please show the definition of point; this might be a reference-equality-versus-value-equality issue.

Comment: Assuming you are using `List<T>`, the msdn docs on [List<T>.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) - tells you exactly how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (l.Any(a => a.x == po.x && a.y == po.y))
```

To addresss the full issue, try this:

```
l = l.Where(a => a.x != po.x || a.y != po.y);
```

That should give you the remaining items without duplicates.

Comment: well apparently it gives some condition true, i cant really check the whole program cause .remove doesnt work, can i get the index from Any too?

Comment: @user3161621 You could use the IndexOf linq method (check for -1) together with List.RemoveAt

Comment: I've added to my answer.  It sounds like you don't actually want to remove anything, but simply filter

Answer (score 1):

You either have to override `Equals` to get `Contains` working as expected or use LINQ:

```
l = l.Where(p => p.X != po.X || p.Y != po.Y).ToList();
```

Presuming that two points are equal if x and y are equal.

Here is an example with a class that overrides `Equals` + `GethashCode`:

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Point p2 = obj as Point;
        if (p2 == null) return false;
        return X == p2.X && Y == p2.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + X;
            hash = hash * 23 + Y;
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use [`List.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which uses `Equals` under the hood. You don't need to check if the list contains the object:

```
bool contained = l.Remove(po);
```

Comment: yes great, this is fantastic, also more easy for when i have something more complicated i can simply adjust the Equals to make it work, ty

Answer (score 0):

You have to define how to compare two `Point` class instances, i.e. what makes them equal?

In your case, you would like them to be equal when the x and y values are both the same, right?

Take you `Point` class and make it inherit the `IEqualityComparer<Point>` interface. Implement this interface:

```
class Point : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    private int _x;
    public int x
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { _x = value; }
    }

    private int _y;
    public int y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set { _y = value; }
    }

    public bool Equals(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        // Returns true if both points have the same x and y values
        // Returns false otherwise.
        if (p1 == null || p2 == null)
           return false;

        return (p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point obj)
    {
        return obj.x ^ obj.y;
    }
}
```