# How to make == work as equals?

Tags: c#

So I have this class which I talked about in another topic:

[How to search inside a list for a different instance of a specific element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676738/how-to-search-inside-a-list-for-a-different-instance-of-a-specific-element/23677059#23677059)

I changed the code following the suggestions and it works... but when i just try to compare elsewhere (pointA==pointB) i never get it true (unless ofc they are the same instance).

So i suspect == doesnt call again my overridden equals(object).
What method gets called then? And do i have to override it too or is there a way to just tell it to call my already fixed equals ?

Comment: Why can you not just call X.Equals(Y)? == defaults to testing for equality of instance references. Another option is to override the == operator.

Comment: All this is well explained here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Here's all you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx (look for _"Overriding Operator =="_)

Comment: well i cant just call X.Equals(Y) because i already wrote some code... its not really easy to find the == between thousands of others that doesnt need change...

Answer (score 3):

`==` is an operator and does not call a method. You can do operator overloading in C#:

```
public static bool operator==(Class a, Class b) {
  return a.field == b.field; // or whatever you want to compare
}
```

Be careful though, this can lead to hard to understand code, since `==` is usually used for reference comparison.

---

Usually, when overriding equality comparison in classes, you take the following approach:

```
protected bool Equals(Class other)
{
    return Equals(this.field, other.field);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return Equals((Class)obj);
}

public static bool operator ==(Class left, Class right)
{
    return Equals(left, right);
}
```

It's good practice to also override `GetHashCode()`. And don't forget to overload `operator!=`

Comment: `a == b` will result in `StackOverFlowException`

Comment: Fixed. The comparison statement was just a dummy placeholder.

Comment: Meaning i just leave it like it is unless its the specific combination of classes i want to change? (ie if (a is myclass && b is myclass){my equals logic}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is?

A == B evaluates whether A refers to the same object as B. Not the same value, but the same exact reference. Why you would be using == to compare dissimilar objects makes no sense. If you're comparing strings, use .toString() or .equals(), or write your own method to compare your object..

Just make sure you understand what == means, or else you will have no luck using it in your logic.

Comment: It seems more intuitive to me to use == but maybe you are right i should just be more careful from now on.

Comment: It's not that you need to be careful. You just need to know exactly what you're asking. Truthfully, I know I'm still primed to make many mistakes like this one. Have a look for a a better explanation than mine, there will be plenty of them..